# Chart image without legend

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

When using chart.getImage(), i get the chart but the legend doesn't come along with this. This has been marked as an Ext bug for over a year now. I was wondering if anyone has a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue and unfortunately there is no workaround for this issue in ext for now. But in my application, what I did was to use `html2canvas` to download the chart with legends, title and other custom sprites. `html2canvas` is a free and lightweight software.

For browsers which supports download attribute, you can use the following code.

```
var chart = chartObj.down('chart');
html2canvas(chart.el.dom, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var myMsg = Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox', {
      closeAction: 'destroy'
    });
    myMsg.show({
      title: 'Confirm Download',
      message: 'Would you like to download the chart as an image?',       
      icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
      buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
      closeAction: 'destroy',
      height: 165,
      width: 350
    });
    var button = myMsg.query("button[text=Yes]")[0];
    button.el.dom.setAttribute("download", "Bar Chart.png");
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    button.setHref(dataURL);
  },
  height: chartObj.getHeight() + 500
});
```

For IE, you can code as shown below.

```
Ext.Msg.confirm({
  title: 'Confirm Download',
  message: 'Would you like to download the chart as an image?',
  icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
  buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
  closeAction: 'destroy',
  height: 165,
  width: 350,
  fn: function(btn) {
    if (btn === 'yes') {
      var chartObj = button.up('chart-container');
      html2canvas(chartObj.down('chart[hidden=false]').el.dom, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          window.navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), 'Bar Chart.png');
        },
        height: chartObj.getHeight() + 500
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Refer more about [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll check it out.